# How to rewrite this code using lambdas and streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

```
 public class Java_03 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> listOfEven = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i+1)
                                    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                                    .limit(10)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> listOf3 = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i+1)
                                    .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0)
                                    .limit(10)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // how to rewrite this code using lambdas and streams ?
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (int a : listOf3) {
        map.put(listOfEven.get(i), a);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(map);
 } 
}
```

I want to write this code using lambdas and stream I've tried alot but failed. please help.

map should contain: key - multiplication table of 2 and value - multiplication table of 3
for eg - {2=3, 4=6, 6=9, 8=12, 10=15, 12=18, 14=21, 16=24, 18=27, 20=30}

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Your code above already uses lambdas and streams. Does it not work? What else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: cannot paste my code in comment!

Comment: @KushalMaharana just edit your question

Comment: the code which is in comment should be done using lambda and streams.

Comment: @KushalMaharana oh man... your question is badly formatted I think this is how people missed your point

Comment: zipping 2 collections together is ugly, you should rather build your results from a single collection like http://ideone.com/pUiNcd

Comment: @zapl: that’s going into the right direction, but `Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(10)` should be replaced with `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).boxed()`…

Comment: Of course, if all that matters is the output, you can simply use `System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).mapToObj(i -> i*2+"="+i*3) .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}")));`

Answer (score 0):

The method `Collectors.toMap` can be used to do the requested.

Sample (count holds the counter):-

```
int[] count = {0};

listOf3.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x->listOfEven.get(count[0]++), x->x))
```

Running Example :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listOfEven = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i+1)
                                        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                                        .limit(10)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> listOf3 = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i+1)
                                        .filter(i -> i % 3 == 0)
                                        .limit(10)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

         int[] count = {0};
         System.out.println(listOf3.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x->listOfEven.get(count[0]++), x->x)));
         }
```

Comment: This abuse of an array is a discouraged code style. Besides that, this code produces an unspecified type of map, not a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.range(0, listOf3.size()).forEach(i -> map.put(listOfEven.get(i), listOf3.get(i)));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.